# Java how to return a generic type that extends an interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, linked-list, return

I have an interface named IDedObject and I am making a linkedlist class that uses generics that extend the IDedObject interface. In the linkedList class, I have a function that tries to find a given item based on it's data, and then returns that item. I am getting an error that says

> Incompatible types. Required: AnyType. Found: IDedObject

This is what my code looks like:

Interface:

```
public interface IDedObject {
    public int getID();
    public void printID();
}
```

LinkedList:

```
public class singlyLinkedList<AnyType extends IDedObject>  {

    public Node<AnyType> endMarker;
    public Node<AnyType> beginMarker;

    AnyType findID(int ID){
        Node curNode = beginMarker;
        while(curNode.getNext() != endMarker){
            if (curNode.getData().getID() == ID){
                return curNode.getData();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Node<AnyType extends IDedObject>{
    public Node(AnyType d, Node<AnyType> n){
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public AnyType getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public AnyType data;
    private Node<AnyType> next;

    private int theSize;
}
```

I appreciate any help with this. It's for a homework assignment, so i'm required to use a generic the extends IDedObject.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you extending the interface? Implement it, those functions dont do anything as they dont have any body to do anything

Comment: @BlooB I have another class that does implement the interface. In the main function, I need to use the LinkedList I created and populate it with the object that implements the interface.

Comment: Post the main() method, and more details about the error.

Comment: Using raw types `Node` for `curNode` and as the return type for `getNext()` probably has something to do with your error.

Comment: I fixed the problem. See my answer below. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing

```
Node curNode = beginMarker;
```

to

```
Node<AnyType> curNode = beginMarker;
```

in the findID function in the LinkedList class. Not sure how I missed that.